# ExportAsFixedFormat cutting second page off

Tags: excel, vba

I'm saving sheets of an Excel workbook as a pdf.  The first sheet of the 2nd pdf ("#Occupants") is 2 pages when printed.  However, the .pdf file cuts off the second page.

What am I missing here?

```
Sub SavePDF()
    saveCensus = "\Census " & Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yy") & ".pdf"
    Sheets(Array("A BLDG", "B BLDG", "C BLDG", "SUMMARY")).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & saveCensus, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

    saveSnapshot = "\Snapshot " & Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yy") & ".pdf"
    Sheets(Array("#Occupants", "Snapshot")).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & saveSnapshot, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: If you export the #Occupants sheet by itself does the full content get included?

Comment: @TimWilliams:  No, it still cuts it off when it's by itself.

Comment: I found it.  When I looked at it in View -> Page Break Preview, the page didn't include the cut-off part.  Adjusted the page break and it worked.